# Play Framework [2.4.x]: Difference between a script file as an Asset, a Public file, and/or Header?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.4

I have a confusion on where to use the scripts (e.g., JS, CoffeeScript) and the rule/idea behind it.

In play I can use a script in the `app/assets/javascripts` and/or `/public/javascripts` folder and/or within the `head` and then `script` tag. What is the difference? What rule should I follow here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your main confusion is about *Compiled Assets* and *Unmanaged Assets*. Basically, compiled assets in Play must be defined in the `app/assets` directory. **They are handled by the build process and sources are compiled into standard JavaScript, CSS, etc. files**.

The generated files are distributed as standard resources into the same `public/` folder as other unmanaged assets, *meaning that there is no difference in the way you use them once compiled*.

For example, a `LESS` source file at `app/assets/stylesheets/main.less` will be available as a standard resource at `public/stylesheets/main.css`. Play will compile `main.less` automatically.

Also, play's documentation has detailed topic on [Assets](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Assets).

Comment: I agree with Ali and want to add that templates (that include much JavaScript) are stored in app/views. Templates in Play are in Twirl and also compiled. More info in https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaTemplates.

Comment: Did you mean uncompiled assets? Because your wrote compile assets and then you wrote 'sources are compiled'.

Comment: Yes. In fact they are to-be-compiled assets or sources like less

Comment: By compiled assets i mean the assets that you want them to be compiled.

Comment: @AliDehghani This is the best/only answer I got so far. However could you also update your answer and point out that should I touch the public folder or not? So the front-end team should be only be able to update the /assets/javascripts and assets/stylesheets folder and leave the public folder alone?

Comment: The front end team could update both `/assets` and `/public`. They will use the `/assets` for `LESS`, `Coffee Script`,.. sources that need to be compiled and use the `/public` for adding their plain `css` or `js` files